# Skyrim Legend Acheivment

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, achievements

In Skyrim the lLegend achievement is unlocked when you defeat a legendary dragon. I know I have to be at least level 70 in order to encounter one. Where should I go to find a legendary dragon?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [wiki](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Legendary_Dragon) you need to be level 78+ to encounter a legendary dragon. Also, the best reported location to find one is the [Lost Tongue Overlook](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Lost_Tongue_Overlook). Which is south a ways of Riften. However, when you are above the proper level you should begin to see them elsewhere at other dragon lairs.